# Compare two text two files whilst one contains column with date

Tags: linux, awk, sed, files

I have two text files, one of them contains:

```
...
2018-09-22   FFF1B976-9DDE-11E7-9C3D-6241D7D553BE
2018-09-27   682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
2018-09-27   682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049.bai
2018-09-27   6846DFEC-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
2018-09-27   6846DFEC-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049.bai
...
```

Whilst the other one contains:

```
...
CA9442F2-8C8C-11E7-8637-ABE8E6BF8454
ED3B2906-0117-11E8-BA0B-30D761F1560A
E9A927E4-8B9B-11E7-9435-18B114A47675
373667F0-8B93-11E7-B918-13B114A47675
15D861C4-BB82-11E8-A989-7D57C505C2C3
...
```

What I'd like to achieve is to compare one to another and display only lines older than 30 days.

Comment: Hello @Kamil. Visually, I can tell there is no difference. Kindly would you please add more context to the question and make it clear? Please include int he question the expected output

Comment: "compare one to another" -- with what comparison rules?

Comment: @Goro Above there are only fragment of files. The one with dates has 38289 lines, while the other one has 28. I need to find out if there are lines in the smaller file occurring in the bigger list but with date older than 30 days. I hope that helped.

Comment: Please add that information into the body of your question.

Comment: Not a single match between the samples - that doesn't really help to infer what you need, as your description is quite vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find lines older than 30 days with GNU tools:

```
awk -v month_ago="$(date -d '30 days ago' '+%F')" '
    NR == FNR {ids[$1]; next}
    $1 < month_ago && $2 in ids
' small_file big_file
```

This reads the small file first (when NR == FNR), storing the values in an array.
Then for lines in the big file, where the date is older than 30 days and the 2nd field has appeared in the smaller file, print that line.

Comment: I want to check each line from the second file against the first one, but display only lines which are 30 days old.